# Convert Area Density to Volumetric Mass Density

Tags: physics

If the area density is 5.5kg/m², then what is its volumetric density in kg/m³?;)

The thickness is 1/8 inch.

I'm not getting the answer I'm being told is the correct answer and going nuts here;)

What is the formula here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A first step is converting the ${1\over8}$ inch to a metric quantity. You have obtained $0.0031$ m. It follows that your one square meter sheet is in reality a box of volume

$V=1$ m${}^2 \times0.0031$ m = $0.0031$ m${}^3\ $.

Since this "box" weighs $5.5$ kg the  volumetric density $\rho$ of the material is given by

$\rho={\displaystyle{5.5 \>{\rm kg}\over0.031\>{\rm m}^3}}=1774.2\>$ kg/m${}^3$.

That's my last word on this matter.

Comment: right, which is 3.1mm or 0.0031m. I can't just add this to the square meter mass.

Comment: I'm sorry; I don't get it. The answer should be in kg/m³

Comment: Thank you, but this is exactly what I arrive at, but when I ask the supplier he says: "The Acoustiblok Blok 16 is 5.5 kilograms per square meter. A small roll of material that is. 54” x 8” x8” with a length of 30 feet unrolled  has a density of 33.79 kilo/2.109 cubic meter". So, this doesn't make sense to me, at all;)